# find linear polynomial g that is closest to f, where $f(x) = e^x$ and the distance between the two

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, orthonormal

In the real linear space [-1,1] with inner product $\int^1_{-1} f(x)g(x)\,dx$. Find the linear polynomial $g$ nearest to $f$ and find $||g -f||^2$ for this $g$.

My problem is that I simply don't know how to do this. All the examples that involve projections (maybe even Graham-Schmidt here?) were all vectors. So I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The set of continuous functions on [-1, 1] is a vector space, so these are all "vectors" too. Just write $g(x) = ax + b$, compute $\langle g-f, g-g \rangle$, and you'll get an expression involving $a$ and $b$. Now minimize it by varying $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy question to answer once we have an orthonormal basis for the functions we're using to approximate $e^x$.  In this case, we are approximating $e^x$ using *linear polynomials*.

That is, we'd like an *orthonormal basis* for the subspace (of all real functions on $[-1,1]$) spanned by $\{1,x\}$.  Let's use the Graham-Schmidt process:
$$
\|1\|_2 = \sqrt{\langle 1,1 \rangle} = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 (1)^2\,dx} = \sqrt{2}\\
u_1 = \frac{1}{\|1\|_2} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}
\\
\langle x, u_1 \rangle = 
\int_{-1}^1 x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} dx = 0
\\
v_2 = x - \langle x, u_1 \rangle u_1 = \cdots
$$
Can you take it from there?  You should find $u_2 = x$, so that $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\}$ is an orthonormal basis.  From there, we have
$$
e^x \approx
\langle e^x, u_1\rangle u_1 + 
\langle e^x, u_2\rangle u_2
$$

Comment: where are you getting {1,x}?

Comment: What do we mean by "linear polynomial"?  That's where I'm getting $\{1,x\}$

Comment: I still don't know what {1,x} means.

Comment: how does e^x not play a factor in any of your calculations?

Comment: $\{1,x\}$ is the basis consisting of the functions $f(x) = 1$ (represented by "$1$"), and the function $g(x) = x$ (represented by "$x$").  The space of linear polynomials is the subspace spanned by the two functions (remember that functions are the vectors of our vector space) $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  That is, $\{f(x),g(x)\}$ forms a basis of our subspace.

Comment: explain the first line (the first one with an integral)? where are you getting <1,1>? I think I got except for that point.

Comment: That's the inner product of $f(x)$ with $f(x)$, where $f(x) = 1$.  If $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is an inner product, then the norm derived from that inner product is $\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}$

Comment: f(x) = e^x. So how can you define it to be = to 1?

Comment: I forgot that we had already used $f$ and $g$.  The letters aren't terribly important though.  If it helps, pretend that I said $p(x) = 1$ and $q(x) = x$, and make replacements accordingly.

Comment: why didn't you normalize $v_2$?

Comment: Try it.  Check that $\|v_2\| = 1$

Comment: No. If $v_2$ = $x$, then <x,x>$ = \int_{-1}^1 x^2$ = $(2/3)$

Comment: Oh, whoops, my mistake.